# Is there anything wrong with my interpretation of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, meaning-in-context

I'm not sure about the meaning of

> Flights arriving on Jet Green Air have been delayed intermittently.

This sentence is found on [this website](http://www.english-test.net/toeic/listening/airport_employee_is_announcing_flight_delays_through_loudspeaker_system.html#TOEIC_Listening_Comprehension).

The following is my interpretation of this sentence:

- *Jet Green Air* is a company.
- *Flights arriving on Jet Green Air* refers to the company's flights that have arrived at this airport.
- *delayed intermittently* means that some of the flights were delayed, some were not (Actually I'm not sure how delay can be intermittent).

Is there anything wrong with my interpretation?

Comment: More importantly "Jet Green Air" is not just a company it is an airline.  They have many flights arriving- some have been delayed, some have not.

Comment: `I'm not sure how delay can be intermittent` Imagine you're watching a movie. The audio and video are in sync. Suddenly, they go out of sync. After a while, they're in sync again. But a few minutes later, they go out of sync again. And then they go even further out of sync. And then everything's normal again. The audio/video delay has been intermittent. However, this doesn't work for a flight's arrival time, since there is only **one** arrival time per flight. Logically, this means that we're referring to **some** flights (out of **many**) to have been delayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more than the fact that some flights were delayed and some weren't.  *Intermittently* means at irregular intervals, so there was no predictable pattern of the delays.

Also note that although a single delay cannot be intermittent, the sentence is talking about flights, plural, so the intermittency describes the unpredictability of which flights were delayed and which weren't.